# macOS get a file's "allocated size" from terminal?

Tags: terminal, filesystem

I'm on a Macbook Pro running macOS 12.2.1 (so using the APFS filesystem.)

I noticed some strange behavior when creating a large "dummy file" using the `mkfile` utility.
(`/usr/sbin/mkfile`)

I created a 5 GB file with the command:

```sh
mkfile -n 5g test.txt
```

Then, to confirm it worked, I ran the `du` command. (`/usr/bin/du`).

```sh
du -hs ./test.txt
```

But I got an unexpected outcome:

```sh
4.0K    ./test.txt
```

I went to the file in Finder and looked at the file info, and saw there were two different sizes.
[image: Top line highlighted displays the size as 5 Gigabytes. However, further down it displays the text: "4 KB on disk"]

After some further digging, I found this info on the `mkfile` man page:

```sh
OPTIONS
     -n     Create an empty filename.  The size is noted, but disk blocks aren't
            allocated until data is written to them.
```

So I wanted to know, is there a command that will let me see the *allocated* file size?

Comment: 4k is the allocated file size. As the description for `-n` says: but disk blocks aren't
            allocated until data is written to them.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I would most likely use something like `dd bs=1024k count=5120 if=/dev/zero of=myfile`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You can see the requested, not yet allocated size with `ls -l test.txt`: `-rw-------  1 jaume  staff  5368709120 Mar  5 11:55 test.txt` or `ls -lh test.txt`, if your prefer a more readable output: `-rw-------  1 jaume  staff   5.0G Mar  5 11:55 test.txt`.

Comment: @jaume That worked perfectly. The other solution also worked, so if either of you guys want to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept!

Comment: @EliRichardson Thank you for your feedback! I took up the gauntlet and added an answer :-) (including some background information about what's happening behind the scenes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Displaying allocated file size vs. file size reported by the file sytem

You can display the **allocated file size**, that is, how much disk space `test.txt` takes up in the file system, with this command:

```
du -h test.txt
```

In contrast, the **file size reported by the file system** may or may not coincide with the allocated file size. To display it, use this command:

```
ls -l test.txt
```

(You can use `ls -lh test.txt` instead if you prefer the file size to be more readable.)

### Sparse files

How come `test.txt` takes up only 4KB of disk space, but the file system reports that its size is 5GB?

This is a clever functionality that (most) file systems offer: instead of spending time and disk space to create a file that contains no data, it is more efficient to create an empty file, set its metadata to report 5BG of size, and only allocate disk space when actual data is added to the file.

And that's what the `-n` option of `mkfile` is all about:

- If you use `mkfile -n`, you will create a sparse file, which is somewhat similar to *buying a train ticket without booking a seat*. The train company won't reserve any seat for you (that is, no seat is allocated).
- However, if you use `mkfile` without the `-n` option, for example:

  ```
  mkfile 5g test.txt
  ```

  the file will be created and 5GB will be allocated, in a way similar to  *buying a train ticket and booking a seat*: the seat is reserved for you and nobody except you can use it (that is, the seat is allocated).

Summarizing, when creating a file, the disk space can be either:

- be allocated (that is, reserved in the file system so that no other file can use it) which, for example, may help prevent the file from becoming fragmented
- or, alternatively, you can request that the disk space not be allocated, which will create a sparse file. A sparse file is efficient, because it only occupies disk space when it contains data.

As pointed out by [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside) in their comment, you can "fill" the sparse file with data using `dd`, for example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt bs=1024k count=5120
```

so that the allocated file size and the file size reported by the file system match.

For more information on sparse files, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file.

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for!